# jquery show/hide with slow input not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hide, show

I want to make a simple email input + button form which, once submitted, should be replaced with another div while staying on the same page. I applied jquery's .hide("slow") on the form and .show("slow") on the 2nd div and while it does show/hide the elements, it doesn't apply the smooth transition.

What am I doing wrong??

Live example: https://codepen.io/mcancode/pen/vYKXmbr

The code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <style>
#subscribed > div > p {
  display: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
 
  <main>
    <section id="newsletter">
      <div id="unsubscribed">
        <h3>Subscribe to our newsletter to get 10% off your next purchase</h3>
        <form id="newsletter-form">
          <div>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
            <button type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>  
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="subscribed">
        <div>
          <p>Thank you for subscribing! You should receive an email with the discount code in the next 5 minutes.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-----------------END OF NEWSLETTER---------->

  </main>

  <!--JS files...-->
  <!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
  
$(() => {

  //check when newsletter form submitted
  $("#newsletter-form").submit((event)=> {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#unsubscribed").hide("slow");
    $("#subscribed>div>p").show("slow");
  })
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a few things.

1. Target the inner element to hide - you can't target a wrapper element ("newsletter") hide it and then show one of it's children.  You'll want to target - "unsubscribed".
2. Give the other area you want to fade into view a starting style to hide it ("subscribed") style="display:none"
3. It looks like the version of jquery you're referencing does not include this animation - I referenced an updated version of jquery after your original reference (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <style>
</style>

</head>
<body>
 
  <main>
    <section id="newsletter">
      <div id="unsubscribed">
        <h3>Subscribe to our newsletter to get 10% off your next purchase</h3>
        <form id="newsletter-form">
          <div>
            <input value="sample@email.com" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
            <button type="submit">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>  
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="subscribed" style="display:none;">
        <div>
          <p>Thank you for subscribing! You should receive an email with the discount code in the next 5 minutes.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-----------------END OF NEWSLETTER---------->

  </main>

  <!--JS files...-->
  <!-- jQuery and JS bundle w/ Popper.js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  
$(() => {

  //check when newsletter form submitted
  $("#newsletter-form").submit((event)=> {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#unsubscribed").hide("slow");
    $("#subscribed").show("slow");
  })
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated the jquery reference as per your suggestion and it worked. Thank you so much, I would've never figured it out on my own!